# Application behaving weird in ubuntu, but working fine in windows

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, ubuntu, struts

I am having a simple java based web application (using servlets, jsp and struts framework). The application is using mysql as database server and tomcat as application server.

The application works fine on windows, but when I deploy the same application in ubuntu it gives me the following error:

```
### Error querying database.  Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'dbconnect.ACT_GE_PROPERTY' doesn't exist
The error occurred while setting parameters
SQL: select VALUE_ from ACT_GE_PROPERTY where NAME_ = 'schema.version'
Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'dbconnect.BDB_PROPERTIES' doesn't exist
at org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:23)
at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:104)
at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:95)
at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectOne(DefaultSqlSession.java:59)
at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectOne(DefaultSqlSession.java:54)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.db.DbSqlSession.getDbVersion(DbSqlSession.java:741)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.db.DbSqlSession.dbSchemaCheckVersion(DbSqlSession.java:697)
```

In the mysql database there are two tables created in the dbconnect database one with the uppercase name (i.e ACT_GE_PROPERTY) and one in the lowercase (i.e, act_ge_properties), these tables are been created automatically by the application.

When I run the application on windows only one table is created in lowercase as act_ge_properties, but in ubuntu two tables are created one in uppercase and one in lowercase i.e, ACT_GE_PROPERTY and act_ge_properties.

I don't know what the problem is, can anyone help me out?

**EDIT**

Error:

```
04:08:20,856 [main] ERROR org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext  - Error while closing command context
org.activiti.engine.ActivitiException: no activiti tables in db. set <property name="databaseSchemaUpdate" to value="true" or value="create-drop" (use create-drop for testing only!) in bean processEngineConfiguration in activiti.cfg.xml for automatic schema creation
at   org.activiti.engine.impl.db.DbSqlSession.dbSchemaCheckVersion(DbSqlSession.java:719)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.db.DbSqlSession.performSchemaOperationsProcessEngineBuild(DbSqlSession.java:1111)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.SchemaOperationsProcessEngineBuild.execute(SchemaOperationsProcessEngineBuild.java:25)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandExecutorImpl.execute(CommandExecutorImpl.java:24)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContextInterceptor.execute(CommandContextInterceptor.java:61)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.LogInterceptor.execute(LogInterceptor.java:31)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.ProcessEngineImpl.<init>(ProcessEngineImpl.java:76)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl.buildProcessEngine(ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl.java:372)
at org.activiti.engine.ProcessEngines.buildProcessEngine(ProcessEngines.java:194)
at org.activiti.engine.ProcessEngines.initProcessEnginFromResource(ProcessEngines.java:167)
at org.activiti.engine.ProcessEngines.init(ProcessEngines.java:98)
at org.activiti.engine.ProcessEngines.getProcessEngine(ProcessEngines.java:224)
at org.activiti.engine.ProcessEngines.getDefaultProcessEngine(ProcessEngines.java:217)
at org.activiti.rest.servlet.ActivitiServletContextListener.contextInitialized(ActivitiServletContextListener.java:32)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:943)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:778)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:504)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error querying database.  Cause:   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'dbconnect.act_ge_property' doesn't exist
### The error may exist in org/activiti/db/mapping/entity/Property.xml
### The error may involve defaultParameterMap
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### SQL: select VALUE_ from ACT_GE_PROPERTY where NAME_ = 'schema.version'
```

Comment: can you check `ACT_GE_PROPERTY` table is created in mysql?

Comment: @Aniket Yes it is created, one with uppercase and other with lowercase

Comment: But error is showing both `ACT_GE_PROPERTY` and `BDB_PROPERTIES` tables do not exist. On windows `BDB_PROPERTIES` table and on ubuntu `ACT_GE_PROPERTY` I am not getting any relation between these two tables?

Comment: @Aniket There is no bdb_properties table. My bad, I updated the question. Please have a look again

Comment: [read table uppercase and lowercase](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html) Can you update the exception also, it is older one as there is table name `BDB_PROPERTIES`?

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, filenames on disk are case insensitive. However, on Linux, they are case sensitive.

On you Windows MySQL installation, your when your tables are written to the underlying disk file, this case insensitivity is then passed to your database application, meaning the tables names are not case sensitive.

On Linux, conversely, table names  are case sensitive.

MySQL provides a Server System Variable to always cast table-names to lower-case:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lower_case_table_names

Comment: So, where do I set this variable?

Comment: Should I set it to 1 or to 2?

Comment: Setting: I think it's in my.cnf. It's not dynamic so it can't be set with a SET command. Set it to 1.

Comment: I set the value lower_case_table_names = 1 in the my.cnf file, restarted the mysql server, but now getting a different error. Please have a look at the edit

Comment: After setting this variable, the tables got created only once i.e, only in lowercase in mysql database. Previously, they were created twice once in uppercase and once in lowercase.

Comment: what do you get when you go to the mysql command prompt and `show tables;` ?